# App's notification options no longer enabling

Tags: notifications, push-notifications

The app in question is "Final Fantasy Brave Exvius". I've checked with their subreddit, and only one person noted they have a similar issue.

Using Samsung S20 FE and this was not a problem from near its release date, until about a month ago.

I noticed that the app is no longer giving notifications.

If I go into the app itself, it's missing the notification option all together.

If I go into the general notification settings, the app only appears when toggling on 'System Apps', and when I attempt to toggle it on there, it toggles itself right back off.

A reinstall of the app did not change this behavior.